# How unique is the message ID generated by Solace System's applience?

Tags: solace

How unique is the value returned by com.solacesystems.jcsmp.XMLMessage#getMessageId() received by queue subscriber (via flow)?

The official JavaDoc says:

> Guaranteed messages delivered from the appliance have a
>   appliance-assigned message ID.

But I want to know how unique this ID and could I use it as a DB primary key for this message?

Also the other part of the question: could be this ID changed during message redelivery?

Answer (score 0):

The message ID is only used internally between the appliance and API for acknowledgement of messages.
There is no guarantee that the message ID is unique.

If you need a unique message ID, you will need to make use of `XMLMessage.setApplicationMessageId()` and `XMLMessage.getApplicationMessageId()`.